# Product of groups is subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Consider a group $G$, two subgroups $G_i, H \leq G$ with some $G_{i+1} \unlhd G_i$, and define $H_i := H \cap G_i$. Consider the product
$$H_i G_{i+1} = \{hg \in G \mid h \in H_i, g \in G_{i+1}\}
$$
Why is it the case that this set is a subgroup of $G_i$?

Comment: Both $H_i$ and $G_{i+1}$ are subgroups of $G_i$ and the latter one is normal. Therefore the product must be a subgroup.

Comment: That is exactly the statement, yes.

Comment: @Jos That is *exactly* the proof: the product of two subgroups, one of which is normal, is always a subgroup.

Comment: More generally, if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, the $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if the sets $HK=\{hk\mid h\in H, k\in K\}$ and $KH=\{kh\mid k\in K, h\in H\}$ are equal. As a consequence, if one of $H$ and $K$ is normal, say $H$, then since for *each* $k\in K$ we have $Hk=kH$, it follows that $HK=KH$ and hence $HK$ is a subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both $H_i$ and $G_{i+1}$ are subgroups of $G_i$ and the latter one is normal. Therefore the product must be a subgroup. To see this in elementary way let $h_1g_1, h_2g_2\in H_iG_{i+1},$ then $$h_1g_1(h_2g_2)^{-1}=h_1h_2^{-1}(h_2g_1h_2^{-1})(h_2g_2^{-1}h_2^{-1})$$ is clearly in your product.